# Relation with integer

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let **a** and **b** be two integers. The relation **$\alpha$ $\subseteq$ ZxZ** is defined by **x $\alpha$ y** iff **аx+by=1**. Find all possible integers **a** and **b** for which **$\alpha$**  is nonempty.

For all  **а** and **b** proof existence or absence of each of following properties: irreflexive, symmetric, antysymmetric and transitive.

Can somebody help with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There exist $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $xa+yb=1$ if and only if $\gcd(a,b)=1$. The implication from left to right is an easy exercise, the one from right to left follows from euclid's algorithm. If you do not know this, it basically provides a way to compute $\gcd(a,b)$ by subsequently applying division with remainder. So the pairs $(a,b)$ for which the relation is nonempty are exactly the ones for which $\gcd(a,b)=1$.